# Go Live from sandbox to Production - DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi

I am using docusign sandbox with **abc@xyx.com** account. I have successfully cleared the approval process for integrator key. Now when i click on Go Live with the sandbox integrator key & submit with terms & conditions, it shows me popup to login. My production account credentials which i have registered are **def@xyz.com**. When I enter these credentials it takes me to  account.docusign.com?code=fffff and then redirects to admindemo.docusign.com?dsProdAccountServerAuth?code=fffff and then shows infinite loading and nothing happens.

So Sandbox & Production Credentials should be same. I am not able to Go Live from sandbox to production. Can anyone help with this problem?

Comment: I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign support for assistance with this issue.  Within the U.S., you can call support at 1 (800) 379-9973. Alternatively, you can open a ticket with support using this link: https://support.docusign.com/en/login?from=/en/createCase.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a cookie problem. I suggest trying in an incognito window.

The login issue is that you run the Go Live process from your demo account. But as a part of the Go Live process, you need to log into a **production** account, using an email/pw for a production account for which you are an **administrator**.

You can be temporarily appointed an admin for the production account, or you can have an admin do his or her login during the process.

> Re: So Sandbox & Production Credentials should be same.

**Not correct.** The email/pw of the demo user (who is running the Go Live process) does NOT have to be the same as the admin user for a production account.

The production account is used to *manage* the integration key. The integration key can be *used* with any production account once it has passed the Go Live process.

Comment: Looks like cookie problem that too in chrome. Tried with Firefox and it worked!